# How to hide folder using NtQueryDirectoryFile hook

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

I'm trying to hide a folder from explorer using the NtQueryDirectoryFile hook. I found a function code that hides files:

```
NTSTATUS WINAPI Mine_NtQueryDirectoryFile(IN HANDLE FileHandle, IN HANDLE Event OPTIONAL, IN PVOID ApcRoutine OPTIONAL, IN PVOID ApcContext OPTIONAL,
    OUT PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock, OUT PVOID FileInformation, IN ULONG Length, IN FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS FileInformationClass,
    IN BOOLEAN ReturnSingleEntry, IN PUNICODE_STRING FileName OPTIONAL, IN BOOLEAN RestartScan)
{
    NTSTATUS status = originalNtQueryDirectoryFile(FileHandle, Event, ApcRoutine, ApcContext, IoStatusBlock, FileInformation, Length, FileInformationClass, ReturnSingleEntry, FileName, RestartScan);

    PFILE_FULL_DIR_INFORMATION pFileFullDirInfo;
    PFILE_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION pFileBothDirInfo;


    switch (FileInformationClass) {
    case fileFullDirectoryInformation:
        pFileFullDirInfo = (PFILE_FULL_DIR_INFORMATION)FileInformation;
        while (pFileFullDirInfo->NextEntryOffset) {
            pFileFullDirInfo = (PFILE_FULL_DIR_INFORMATION)((LPBYTE)pFileFullDirInfo + pFileFullDirInfo->NextEntryOffset);
        }
        break;
    case fileBothDirectoryInformation:
        pFileBothDirInfo = (PFILE_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION)FileInformation;
        while (pFileBothDirInfo->NextEntryOffset) {
            pFileBothDirInfo = (PFILE_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION)((LPBYTE)pFileBothDirInfo + pFileBothDirInfo->NextEntryOffset);
        }
        break;
    case fileIdBothDirectoryInformation:

        PFILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION current = (PFILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION)FileInformation;
        while (current->NextEntryOffset) {
            PFILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION next = (PFILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION)((LPBYTE)current + current->NextEntryOffset);

            if (compareToFileName(next, "d.txt") == true) {
                if (next->NextEntryOffset != 0) {
                    next = (PFILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION)((LPBYTE)next + next->NextEntryOffset);
                    current->NextEntryOffset += next->NextEntryOffset;
                }
                else {
                    current->NextEntryOffset = 0;
                }
            }
            else {
                current = next;
            }
        }


        break;
    }

    return status;
}
```

But when I try to specify the folder name instead of the file name and inject the DLL in the explorer, it crashes with an error c0000005, or freezes. I want to understand what the problem is, but I have not found an answer anywhere. Hooking with Microsoft Detours.

I added an entry to the file on every program action. Here is the modified code:

```
NTSTATUS WINAPI Mine_NtQueryDirectoryFile(IN HANDLE FileHandle, IN HANDLE Event OPTIONAL, IN PVOID ApcRoutine OPTIONAL, IN PVOID ApcContext OPTIONAL,
    OUT PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock, OUT PVOID FileInformation, IN ULONG Length, IN FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS FileInformationClass,
    IN BOOLEAN ReturnSingleEntry, IN PUNICODE_STRING FileName OPTIONAL, IN BOOLEAN RestartScan)
{
    std::ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("C:\\log.txt");

    NTSTATUS status = originalNtQueryDirectoryFile(FileHandle, Event, ApcRoutine, ApcContext, IoStatusBlock, FileInformation, Length, FileInformationClass, ReturnSingleEntry, FileName, RestartScan);
    myfile << "1\n";

    PFILE_FULL_DIR_INFORMATION pFileFullDirInfo;
    myfile << "2\n";

    PFILE_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION pFileBothDirInfo;
    myfile << "3\n";


    switch (FileInformationClass) {
    case fileFullDirectoryInformation:
    {
        pFileFullDirInfo = (PFILE_FULL_DIR_INFORMATION)FileInformation;
        myfile << "ffdi 1\n";
        int counter1 = 0;
        while (pFileFullDirInfo->NextEntryOffset) {
            pFileFullDirInfo = (PFILE_FULL_DIR_INFORMATION)((LPBYTE)pFileFullDirInfo + pFileFullDirInfo->NextEntryOffset);
            myfile << "ffdi while iteration ", counter1, "\n";
            counter1++;
        }
        myfile << "ffdi end\n";
    }
    break;
    case fileBothDirectoryInformation:
    {
        pFileBothDirInfo = (PFILE_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION)FileInformation;
        myfile << "fbdi 1\n";
        int counter2 = 0;

        while (pFileBothDirInfo->NextEntryOffset) {
            pFileBothDirInfo = (PFILE_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION)((LPBYTE)pFileBothDirInfo + pFileBothDirInfo->NextEntryOffset);
            myfile << "fbdi while iteration ", counter2, "\n";
            counter2++;
        }
        myfile << "fbdi end\n";
    }
        break;
    case fileIdBothDirectoryInformation:
    {
        PFILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION current = (PFILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION)FileInformation;
        myfile << "fibdi 1\n";
        int counter3 = 0;
        while (current->NextEntryOffset) {
            myfile << "cycle start\n";
            PFILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION next = (PFILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION)((LPBYTE)current + current->NextEntryOffset);
            myfile << "PFILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION ", next, " = (PFILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION)((LPBYTE)", current, " + ", current, "->NextEntryOffset)";

            if (compareToFileName(next, "detours") == true) {

                myfile << "if (compareToFileName(", next, ", detours) == true) == true\n";

                if (next->NextEntryOffset != 0) {

                    myfile << "if (", next, "->NextEntryOffset != 0) == true\n";

                    next = (PFILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION)((LPBYTE)next + next->NextEntryOffset);

                    myfile << next, " = (PFILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION)((LPBYTE)", next, " + ", next, "->NextEntryOffset);\n";

                    current->NextEntryOffset += next->NextEntryOffset;

                    myfile << current, "->NextEntryOffset += ", next, "->NextEntryOffset; \n";

                }
                else {
                    myfile << "if (", next, "->NextEntryOffset != 0) == false\n";

                    current->NextEntryOffset = 0;

                    myfile << "current->NextEntryOffset = 0 \n";

                }
            }
            else {

                myfile << "if (compareToFileName(", next, ", detours) == true) == false\n";

                current = next;
            }
            myfile << "fibdi while iteration ", counter3, "\n";
            counter3++;
        }

    }
        break;
    }
    myfile << "end \n";
    myfile.close();
    return status;
}
```

After the DLL injection, explorer crashed again. Here is the content of the C:\log.txt file after the injection:

1

2

3

fibdi 1

end

The explorer crashed only after I go to the directory with the folder specified in the code

Comment: Add a buch of logging calls (e.g. fprintf to a file + fflush), see how far it goes, extend your wuestion with those findings.

Comment: Error `c0000005` is an Access Violation.  You are accessing invalid memory somewhere.  You need to debug your code to figure out where exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need hook not only `NtQueryDirectoryFile` but also `NtQueryDirectoryFileEx`

mandatory check `status` returned by original API. you need process returned buffer only in case it returns `STATUS_SUCCESS`. you code not do this, what is critical error.

you not handle asynchronous I/O case - i.e when API return `STATUS_PENDING`. do this is very not simply, in case `FileHandle` bind to IOCP, because need filter returned data in another place/time. however probably explorer and most file browsers never use asynchronous I/O here.

your logic how filter returnded data is complete wrong. say with
`while (pFileBothDirInfo->NextEntryOffset)` you always lost last entry and many other errors. possible implementation can be next:

```
void FilterBuffer(_Inout_ PVOID FileInformation, 
                  _Inout_ PULONG_PTR pLength,
                  _In_ FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS FileInformationClass,
                  ...)
{
    ULONG FileNameOffset, FileNameLengthOffset;

    switch (FileInformationClass)
    {
    case FileBothDirectoryInformation:
        FileNameOffset = offsetof(FILE_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION, FileName);
        FileNameLengthOffset = offsetof(FILE_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION, FileNameLength);
        break;

    case FileIdBothDirectoryInformation:
        FileNameOffset = offsetof(FILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION, FileName);
        FileNameLengthOffset = offsetof(FILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION, FileNameLength);
        break;

    case FileDirectoryInformation:
        FileNameOffset = offsetof(FILE_DIRECTORY_INFORMATION, FileName);
        FileNameLengthOffset = offsetof(FILE_DIRECTORY_INFORMATION, FileNameLength);
        break;

    case FileFullDirectoryInformation:
        FileNameOffset = offsetof(FILE_FULL_DIR_INFORMATION, FileName);
        FileNameLengthOffset = offsetof(FILE_FULL_DIR_INFORMATION, FileNameLength);
        break;

    case FileIdFullDirectoryInformation:
        FileNameOffset = offsetof(FILE_ID_FULL_DIR_INFORMATION, FileName);
        FileNameLengthOffset = offsetof(FILE_ID_FULL_DIR_INFORMATION, FileNameLength);
        break;

    case FileNamesInformation:
        FileNameOffset = offsetof(FILE_NAMES_INFORMATION, FileName);
        FileNameLengthOffset = offsetof(FILE_NAMES_INFORMATION, FileNameLength);
        break;

    default: return ; 
    }

    PVOID LastEntry = 0;
    ULONG_PTR Length = *pLength, NewLength = 0;
    PVOID Destination = FileInformation;
    ULONG NextEntryOffset = 0;

    do 
    {
        (PBYTE&)FileInformation += NextEntryOffset;

        NextEntryOffset = 
            reinterpret_cast<PFILE_NAMES_INFORMATION>(FileInformation)->NextEntryOffset;

        UNICODE_STRING FileName = {
            *(USHORT*)RtlOffsetToPointer(FileInformation, FileNameLengthOffset),
            FileName.Length,
            (PWSTR)RtlOffsetToPointer(FileInformation, FileNameOffset)
        };

        DbgPrint(">%wZ<\n", &FileName);

        if (KeepEntry(&FileName, ...))
        {
            LastEntry = FileInformation;

            ULONG_PTR EntrySize = NextEntryOffset ? NextEntryOffset : Length;

            if (Destination != FileInformation)
            {
                memcpy(LastEntry = Destination, FileInformation, EntrySize);
            }

            (PBYTE&)Destination += EntrySize;

            NewLength += EntrySize;
        }

        Length -= NextEntryOffset;

    } while (NextEntryOffset);

    if (LastEntry)
    {
        reinterpret_cast<PFILE_NAMES_INFORMATION>(LastEntry)->NextEntryOffset = 0;
    }

    *pLength = NewLength;
}
```

and use it from hook

```
        if (status == STATUS_SUCCESS)
        {
            FilterBuffer(FileInformation, &iosb.Information, FileInformationClass, ...);

            if (!iosb.Information)
            {
                status = STATUS_NO_MORE_FILES;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Using your advice, I fixed the errors in the code, now everything works fine!